# Npx Hardhat Error: receiving unexpected "Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'"

Tags: hardhat

Did npm install --save-dev hardhat and then did npx hardhat to check if it was installed properly but it's not working checked both 'hardhat-config-js' and 'package.json' for nomicfoundation dependencies and it is there but still I'm getting "unexpected error"

I uninstalled my current node.js version 19.1.0 and reinstalled the 18.12.1 LTS version

Answer (score 0):

Start with `npm init` followed by `npm install --save-dev hardhat`

`npx hardhat` will scaffold the project including creation of the `hardhat.config.js and a dummy contract.

Source: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/creating-a-new-hardhat-project

Answer (score 0):

Install this package:

```
npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
```